MSVC Error: Template class with int64_t member - 'followed by __int64 is illegal'
Working on cross compiling this FLOSS, I'm trying to compile a simple template class that uses int64_t as a template parameter, but MSVC (Visual Studio 2019) gives me errors about illegal type usage. Here's a minimal example:
#include <cstdint>

class test_class {
public:
    template<typename T>
    class inner_class {
    private:
        T value;
    public:
        inner_class() : value(T()) {}
        bool operator==(const inner_class<T>& other) const {
            return value == other.value;
        }
    };

    inner_class<int64_t> _int64;  // Error here
};

int main() {
    test_class t;
    return 0;
}

When compiling with:
cl.exe /std:c++17 /EHsc /W4 test.cpp

I get these errors:
error C2628: 'test_class::inner_class<int64_t>' followed by '__int64' is illegal (did you forget a ';'?)
error C2208: 'test_class::inner_class<int64_t>': no members defined using this type

I've tried using std::int64_t explicitly and also tried creating type aliases, but still get similar errors. The code compiles fine with GCC and Clang.
Visual Studio version:
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.29.30156 for x64

What I've Tried

Using explicit std:: namespace:

inner_class<std::int64_t> _int64;


Using type aliases:

using int64_type = std::int64_t;
inner_class<int64_type> _int64;


Adding typename keyword:

inner_class<typename std::int64_t> _int64;

All produce the same or similar errors. What am I doing wrong? Is this a MSVC-specific issue?

my guess is that _int64 is reserved. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vJXQ2VOzEs or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier. I can't get an actual standard ref yet but the issue is there I think

@Oersted how come it doesn't throw any errors under Linux?

@Oersted I wouldn't recomment ever using names that start with underscore, but this one is fine per standard. Names that start with single underscore followed by lowercase letter are only reserved in global namespace. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers. My bet would be that the non-standard template parsing that Visual Studio uses is messing up here.

because some identifier syntaxes are reserved for compiler vendor that may or may not use them

@FoadS.Farimani Some names are reserved in C++, compiler may use them for whatever they want. If you do introduce such a name, your code becomes ill-formed, no diagnostic required (i.e., technically you should get compiler error, but standard committee decided it's too hard for compilers to actually detect such problem, so they don't have to).

@Yksisarvinen thx for the precision. Yet renaming the variable solves OP issue, so MSVC is probably overzealous. Yet I think it's considered good practice to never start an identifier with "_" (among other niceties).

Interestingly, the error message says there is __int64 that is the problem. Do you actually have two underscores in the name in your real code?

My bet would be that somewhere in Windows.h there is a #define _int64 __int64.

fun fact _Int64 is accepted whereas it should not...

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/identifiers-int8-int16-int32-int64-single-undersco/339994: "this issue is by design"

So what should I do folks. Is it possible to resolve this issue in the least invasive way possible? I mean can I solve it outside the code through the CMakeLists.txt file or by flags/options for cl.exe?

@Oersted It is not that _Int64 must be rejected, but that using it makes the program have undefined behavior. On the other hand _int64 is, outside the global namespace scope, supposed to be completely fine. That MSVC does not accept this is non-conforming to the standard. The standard library headers must (except for the macro names specifically listed in the standard) not #define any of the non-reserved names. But Windows/MSVC headers are known to incorrectly use names that shouldn't be reserved for historic reasons.

@FoadS.Farimani You seem to have forked the code, wouldn't be feasible to merely rename the variable. Otherwise the original repository seems active, you may fill an issue?

@Oersted if renaming is the only solution, I will do it, but it would be great if I could have an automatic way to find all similar issues and rename them all at once.

Identifiers starting with single and double underline are reserved for thetoolchain(MSVC in this case). Lucky enough for you _int64 and __int64 represent some integral types, and the error was diagnosed early. The general case is IFNDR. Don't ever start your identifiers with underlines.

Minor point: in some languages an "inner class" has some magical relationship to its corresponding "outer class". So I wouldn't name a nested class inner_class because it might suggest to readers of the code that there's something special there.

The "undocumented feature" is no longer undocumented.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/int8-int16-int32-int64?view=msvc-170

@FoadS.Farimani  Is your problem solved?

@MinxinYu-MSFT partly. I can rename _int64 to _int64_ for example, but I still do not understand what is happening under the hood and why do I get such a nonsensical error! I wonder if I can instruct cl.exe directly or via NMake/CMake, to throw more relevant error messages. I am going to test the /Za option below to see what it does.

The document  provided below explains it.
_int64 is synonyms for __int64. And is Microsoft-specific.

never starts any identifer with _. More details in What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?, What are the rules about using an underscore in a C identifier?. Those names are reserved by the standard and using them invokes undefined behavior. That means you have to change the name

@phuclv _int64 is however not reserved in OPs example since it's not in the global scope. Nevertheless, since the exact rules may be hard to remember, avoiding to start identifiers with _ is pretty good.

@FoadS.Farimani "I still do not understand what is happening under the hood" - As I wrote in my answer, MSVC has a type named _int64 which is in conflict with the name you are trying to give your variable.

In your example _int64 is an instance variable. MSVC has a type with that name, so there's a conflict. Just rename the variable:
inner_class<int64_t> int64;  // No error here

This is what MSVC sees when you use try to use _int64 as a variable name:
typedef long long __int64;
typedef __int64 _int64;
inner_class<int64_t> _int64; // _int64 == long long **error**



by flags/options for cl.exe?

Add /Za flag for cl.exe
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/int8-int16-int32-int64?view=msvc-170

For compatibility with previous versions, _int8, _int16, _int32, and
_int64 are synonyms for __int8, __int16, __int32, and __int64 unless compiler option /Za (Disable language extensions) is specified.

